# Iterating over two arrays at a time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I want to iterate over two arrays at the same time, as the values for any given index `i` in array A corresponds to the value in array B.

I am currently using this code, and getting `undefined` when I call `alert(queryPredicates[i])` or `alert(queryObjects[i])`.
 I know my array is populated as I print out the array prior to calling this.

```
//queryPredicates[] and queryObjects[] are defined above as global vars - not in a particular function, and I have checked that they contain the correct information.

function getObjectCount(){
    var variables = queryPredicates.length; //the number of variables is found by the length of the arrays - they should both be of the same length
    var queryString="count="+variables;
    for(var i=1; i<=variables;i++){
        alert(queryPredicates[i]);
        alert(queryObjects[i]); 
    }
```

Comment: What I am asking is, am I doing this the right way. If the code above looks correct, which I think it does, then that means I have some other problem.

Comment: Btw I don't have any errors being detected by Firebug

Comment: Hmm... Hard to see why there would be any problem with the current code—I think you'll need to provide more code.

Comment: Does `queryPredicates` have numerical indexes?

Comment: Try alerting the actual array(s) in the loop (e.g. `alert(queryPredicates);`, `alert(queryObjects);`) and see what that gives you.

Comment: @Steve they weren't being declard - I copied this from old code. But I have done that now (I didn't want them to be globals), but I still get the same error.

Comment: @bschaeffer do you know how I can check the indexes. @Steve will do that now.

Comment: Alerting the arrays in the loop gives a proper answer, i.e. the numbers that have been clicked and I have pushed into the array, so it really seems to be a matter of getting to the correct values. I will try doing this without numerical indexes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value of the `length` property of any array, is the actual number of elements (more exactly, the greatest existing index plus one).

If you try to access this index, it will be always `undefined` because it is outside of the bounds of the array (this happens in the last iteration of your loop, because the `i<=variables` condition).

In JavaScript the indexes are handled from `0` to `length - 1`.

Aside of that make sure that your two arrays have the same number of elements.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I was starting with 1 was that I had a different problem earlier and somehow thought I had read that JS arrays start at 1 ... thanks for this. And then I just simply assumed I had this part correct.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't pick this up! It's lucky that there are some people here that are thinking properly! ;)

Answer (score 3):

If `queryPredicates` does not have numerical indexes, like 0, 1, 2, etc.. then trying to alert the value `queryPredicates[0]` when the first item has an index of `queryPredicates['some_index']` won't alert anything.

Try using a `for` loop instead:

```
stuff['my_index'] = "some_value";

for (var i in stuff)
{
    // will alert "my_index"
    alert(i);

    // will alert "some_value"
    alert(stuff[i]);
}
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, I do understand that, my issue is trying to replicate iterating over two arrays simultaneously in a single loop when I don't use a numerical index. I think it might be as simple as trying to

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in JS are zero based. Length is the actual count.  Your loop is going outside the bounds of the array.